# Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module" in host centos while ssh to ubuntu

Tags: ssh, gtk

When I am logging in via SSH to the Ubuntu 12.04 server from CentOS machine and running the gvim editor then I am getting the error:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pk-gtk-module" .
```

If I am doing SSH from Ubuntu machine then it's not giving any error.

Comment: I assume you're using X forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
sudo apt-get install packagekit-gtk3-module
```

This fixed it for me on Ubuntu server 14.04.

Comment: He's having the issue from a CentOS Machine, if im not mistaken, does not use debian or apt as a package manager.

Comment: On CentOS it'd be: `sudo yum install PackageKit-gtk3-module`